# How to read log file created by a android running program in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to make a c# application which reads log file created by a android RUNNING program in c#. This sounds like application Log Filter or log tool in Eclipse or Android Studio. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your intend is just to open the log file for read-only purposes, you can do so with the following code:

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, 
                                  FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
//do whatever parsing you want here
}
```